Physics messed up after reopening file though everything has been baked and saved prior to closing file

Haven't found a solution to this problem after googling. When I bake my simulations and everything looks good and I save and close the project, when I reopen the file, my simulations have this weird crinkling and wiggle to them (otherwise the simulations seam to work properly).
All simulations are cloth sims, some have more complex meshes on top with surface deform but all sims, even the simple cables you can see here in the back are ether wrinkled or in different positions.
All sims have been baked and I have done zero transformations prior to closing the file but I still have to bake everything again after reopening the file. This wouldn't be a problem but as I use an online render farm to render the final result, they get messed up there. I also have the Disk Cache unchecked on all sims so they should be saved to the file directly.

just a guess: are you sure the simulations use their own caches and the data is not overwritten by another simulation? Have you given the caches unique names?

@Blunder I have just pressed bake all dynamics button and everything has worked well until reopening the file. So I should double click every cloth sim cache and give them a unique name to make it work properly?

@Blunder Update: I tried giving them all a unique name but still running to the same problem/result.
